# How to write correct grammar of sql query statement in asp.net

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server-2008

now I'm facing a problem: I want to get a total number from result='yes' and 'no' from database.
Actually I try a sql query in my sql server studio is working correctly, but when I place the same sql query in the
code of asps.cs, nothing happens, I don't know why. Hope someone can help me to find the problem.

The code as below:

```
String query_risk1 = "SELECT (SELECT count(result) FROM [rampDB].[dbo].[Answers] WHERE [result]='yes' AND [company] = @deName1 AND [questionID] BETWEEN '1.1a' AND '1.1e' )+(SELECT count(result) FROM [rampDB].[dbo].[Answers] WHERE [result]='no' AND [company] = @deName1 AND [questionID] BETWEEN '1.1a' AND '1.1e')"; 
DataSet ds_risk = new DataSet();

SqlDataAdapter riskadapter1 = new SqlDataAdapter(query_risk1, sqlConn);
riskadapter1.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@deName1", site_name));
DataTable risk_table1 = new DataTable();
riskadapter1.Fill(risk_table1);

ds_risk.Tables.Add(risk_table1);
risk_table1 = ds_risk.Tables[0];
grid2.DataSource = ds_risk;
grid2.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN [result] = 'yes' OR [result] = 'no' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) As Result
FROM [rampDB].[dbo].[answers] 
WHERE [company] = @deName1 AND [questionid] BETWEEN '1.1a' AND '1.1e'
```

May be something like this

```
String query_risk1 = "SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN [result] = 'yes' OR [result] = 'no' THEN 1 ELSE END) As Result FROM [rampDB].[dbo].[answers] WHERE [company] = @deName1 AND [questionid] BETWEEN '1.1a' AND '1.1e'"; 
DataSet ds_risk = new DataSet();    
SqlDataAdapter riskadapter1 = new SqlDataAdapter(query_risk1, sqlConn);
riskadapter1.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@deName1", site_name));
DataTable risk_table1 = new DataTable();
riskadapter1.Fill(risk_table1);    
ds_risk.Tables.Add(risk_table1);
risk_table1 = ds_risk.Tables[0];
grid2.DataSource = ds_risk;
grid2.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

your query is similar to this query:

```
SELECT count(result) 
FROM [rampDB].[dbo].[Answers] 
WHERE ([result]='yes' OR [result]='no') AND 
       [company] = @deName1 AND 
       [questionID] BETWEEN '1.1a' AND '1.1e'
```

and finally if you use this query you can tru `ExecuteScaler()` method to get return value of query:

```
SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection("YOUR SQL CONNECTIONSTRING");
SqlCommand    sqlCom = new SqlCommand("THE QUERY", sqlCon);
sqlCom.Parameters.AddWithValue("@deName1", "SOME VALUE");
sqlCon.Open();
int count = (int)sqlCom.ExecuteScaler();
sqlCon.Close();
```